# Python: Can't install .whl package for two python versions on Windows

Tags: python, pip

I have Python 2.7 and 3.4 on my work computer for compatibility reasons with older scripts.

Now I wanted to install "aenum" for Py2.7 but "pip" only installs the package for Py3.4. telling me "aenum-2.0.4-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform".

In the CMD terminal I changed to the designated Python's "site-packages" folder where it's installed in Py3.4.

"pip" was updated before. pip is installed in both Python folders

How can I set this up properly?

Comment: You need to call the `pip` for the version of `python` you're using. How do you call `pip`? Edit the question. eg. `c:\python27\scripts\pip.exe install aenum-2.0.4-py2-none-any.whl`

Comment: If you don't have `pip` for `2.7` see [how to install `pip`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip).

Comment: Now the "pip" containing folder is also added to the "PATH" environment variables but even after a restart windows tells me that "pip2.7" is unknown to the system :(

Comment: Do this: `py -2 -m pip install package`

Comment: abccd I also use this to install "aenum" but the problem that "pip2.7" is unknown to the system is still existing.
How can that be when the "PATH" variable is set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You may have two versions of pip installed i did too and it was a pain but i fixed it myself with the following command: pip2 download/install (enter your package here)

That should fix the issue you have encountered.

Comment: "pip2 download/install 2.7" is an unknown command to windows.
If I either use "pip download 2.7" or "pip install 2.7" the terminal says first "Collecting 2.7" and after it in red letters that there was no version found that satisfies the requirements.

Comment: You need to add python to path after that then you can then install pip and then after that you can do what i said above i do it regularly friend.

Comment: To clarify the pip2 download/install was me being simplistic for you obviously you would need to do one or the other like this... pip2 download (package goes here), then pip2 install (package goes here) and that explains what i meant sorry for you misinterpreting me have a nice day!

Comment: Or you could do this pip2 download (package goes here) && pip2 install (package goes here) and that would complete the command in one line.